# App Minimized Function? Xcode - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Just a quick question to ask how I can check if my app has been minimised? IE Home button been pressed?

Having a problem in my game where it's constantly building up more and more nodes at the top of the screen and I need to call the pause game function when the home button is pressed.

Thanks in advance

PS Xcode 6.4 -Swift

Comment: you can look into app did enter background method in app delegate . That method will get called when home button is pressed when the app is running.

Comment: Thanks!! Is it possible to call a function within GameScene from here or is it out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app goes to background, the function applicationDidEnterBackground in the appDelegate gets called (and then you have something like 5 seconds to clean stuff)

in addition, The system sends the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification in addition to calling the applicationDidEnterBackground: method

so you can listen to this notification

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I'd listen for the notification within GameScene?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(someMethod:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification 
                                           object: nil];